# Can same facebook app id be used for both android and iphone app?

Tags: android, iphone, facebook-graph-api

I have two apps which have same name and same functions. One in android market and one in app store. Currently only with iphone app you can post your score on your facebook wall using the facebook app i created. My question is can i use same app for android also to post the score on user's wall? Will it create any problems if i do that?

Comment: I don't see "android and iphone" option together.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same application ID. You should, in fact, as it'll prevent you from having analytics and user permissions split between the two.

Answer (score 0):

On the facebook developer page you can set how you will use the login account. Than you can select mobile application and set Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

whatever you use for creating app either iPhone, android, blackbarry etc. same app id used in all mobile application.